Проблемы с кодировкой текста
Есть в базе данных записи которые кодировались при помощи программы на Delphi, ниже приведен пример:
text = 'ïðîáëåìà ñ ëåíòî÷íûì ïðèâîäîì'
corrected_text = text.encode('utf-8').decode('cp866')
print(corrected_text)

Который выдает:
├п├░├о├б├л├е├м├а ├▒ ├л├е├н├▓├о├╖├н├╗├м ├п├░├и├в├о├д├о├м

Ктото может подсказать какая кодировка там используется?

https://2cyr.com/decode/?lang=fr вот на этом сайте, можно посмотреть // по-моему это Windows-1251

Интересно, конечно, почему .encode('utf-8').decode('cp866') дало частично читаемый результат

text = 'ïðîáëåìà ñ ëåíòî÷íûì ïðèâîäîì'
corrected_text = text.encode('latin1').decode('windows-1251')
print(corrected_text)

Вывод:
проблема с ленточным приводом

[Program finished]

